# MVC Search Functionality Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a form where users can input information to search for records. I have a ViewModel created to pass the users inputs to the controller.

Here is ViewModel

```
 public class SearchParameters
{
    [DisplayName("First Name:  ")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Last Name:  ")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Alternate Name:  ")]
    public string AltName { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayName("Date of Record:  ")]
    public DateTime? DateOfRecord { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("County:  ")]
    public string County { get; set; }
}
```

This is form to get user data

```
@model GenDB.ViewModels.SearchParameters
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home"))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AltName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AltName)
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateOfRecord)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfRecord)
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.County)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.County)
    <br />
    <br />
    <button type="reset">Clear All Fields</button>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
}
```

This will call the search method from the home controller. My search method below.

```
public ActionResult Search(SearchParameters searchParam)
    {

        var business = new ObituaryBuisnessLogic();
        var model = business.Search(searchParam);
        return View(model.ToList());
    }
```

My business layer class with actual implementation below.

```
public class ObituaryBuisnessLogic
{
    private GenContext Context;
    public ObituaryBuisnessLogic()
    {
        Context = new GenContext();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Obit> Search(SearchParameters parameters)
    {
        var result = Context.Obit.AsQueryable();

        if (parameters != null)
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters.FirstName))
            {
                result = result.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(parameters.FirstName));
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters.LastName))
            {
                result = result.Where(x => x.LastName.Contains(parameters.LastName));
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters.AltName))
            {
                result = result.Where(x => x.AltName.Contains(parameters.LastName));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }    
}
```

My goal is to take the users inputs from the first form, put them into the search parameters model, then I want to query 3 separate tables, all with similar but different structures and models, and return all the results to a view, with 3 partial views for the corresponding tables.

My confusion is coming because I know I need to call the Search method from the Home controller, but then how do I break-off into each other tables controller to query the database and return results.

My thought process is like this.

USER INPUTS PARAMETERS ----> SEARCH METHOD OF HOME CONTROLLER IS CALLED WITH USER INPUTS PASSED IN AS PARAMS -----> (here's my confusion) CALL THREE DIFFERENT INDIVIDUAL CONTROLLER "SEARCH" METHODS, POPULATE THEIR RESPECTIVE MODELS WITH RESULTS, RETURN RESULTS TO RESPECTIVE VIEWS???....

I thought about just putting all of the logic in the Home Controller Search method, but then it confuses me why I even need Controllers for the three other Model classes.

Thank you for your time looking at my question.

Comment: Not 100% sure if I understand your question, but here goes. Leave the single command in your controller. In your business layer, call the search methods against each of the dbs (context.Obit, context.Obit2, etc). Materialize your results into a shared model (obitResult = result.Select(i => new resultViewModel(i)). Optionally, stick those 3 result objects into a container view model to display on the view (viewModel.ObitResults = obitResult)

Comment: @Jonathan - you should put that as an answer - firstly because its correct, and secondly because its not a comment. :-)

Comment: There's just so much ambiguity in the original question, though, I hesitated... but you're probably right :)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if I understand your question, but here goes. Leave the single command in your controller.

In your business layer, call the search methods against each of the dbs (context.Obit, context.Obit2, etc).

Materialize your results into a shared model

```
obitResult = result.Select(i => new resultViewModel(i))
```

Optionally, stick those 3 result objects into a container view model to display on the view

```
viewModel.ObitResults = obitResult
```